# Where's the benefit of static typing, aka why wasn't this caught? Java

Tags: java

I have this code,

```
class Test
{
    public static void  main(String args[])
    {
        String x = "Hello";
        String y = "Bye!";
        System.out.printf("This is %s, this is %s", x);
    }
}
```

And the the java compiler compiled it, but it obviously has an error. My question is, why didn't the compiler catch this error? Where's the benefit of static typing if it can't even catch this small mistake?

Comment: No static type check is performed here, use StringBuilder if you want one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`printf()` takes a String and a vararg array of Objects as argument. Your program passes arguments that conform to these argument types, so the compiler is happy.

The compiler would reject your method call if you did, for example

```
Integer a = 23;
System.out.printf(a, x);
```

because an Integer is not a String.

It seems like you think static typing makes runtime errors impossible. That's not the case at all. The compiler doesn't know what printf() does and what those `%s` mean in the String. It doesn't know that the number of `%s` is supposed to match the number of arguments passed to the method. And even if it did, you could pass a variable of type String, and a variable of type Object[] to the method, whose length and values are only known at runtime, and not at compile time. For example:

```
String s = readPatternFromUser();
Object o = readFirstArgFromUser();
System.out.print(s, o);
```

Comment: But my program didn't conform since the string said it would have two substitutions and I only gave one. Does the compiler not see or care?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian `printf` is a method, not a compile-time substitution thingy.

Comment: String values are not interpreted/compiled/evaluated as Java code. They are just ... String values.

Answer (score 1):

Because the error is a *runtime* error, not a *compile time* error. The string substitution of the two %s happens at runtime. The compiler has no idea that you are "missing" the y parameter.

Comment: thanks, then what would be the differentiation of runtime/compile time?

Comment: Probably best to just google/wiki for that, since it's so fundamental. Learning that stuff from SO comments is not recommended. :)

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: just what it means: runtime time = at the time the program is run, or executed. compile time = at the time the source code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The (static) types passed to the printf() method are correct - it is an illegal argument, which is not discovered until runtime.

This is no different from `Integer.parseInt("foo")` or any of the innumerable other cases of an unsuitable value of the correct type being passed to a method.